# MCMC algorithm for Hierarchical Bayes model with variable number of mixture components

Tags: bayesian, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, gibbs

I am trying to develop an MCMC algorithm for clustering $n$ data-points $y_{1},y_{2},\dots,y_{n}$ using a Gaussian mixture model, but with a prior defined on the number of components K. The hierarchical Bayesian model is specified as follows:

$$\lambda \sim \textbf{Gamma}(\nu_{1},\nu_{2})$$
$$K |\lambda\sim \textbf{Poisson}(\lambda)$$
$$\boldsymbol{\phi}|K,\alpha {\sim} \textbf{Dirichlet}_{K}(\frac{\alpha}{K},\frac{\alpha}{K},\ldots,\frac{\alpha}{K})$$
$$z_{i}|\boldsymbol{\phi},K\overset{i,i.d}{\sim}\textbf{Categorical}(\boldsymbol{\phi})$$
$${\mu}_{l}|K,\mu,\tau^{2}\overset{i,i.d}{\sim}\textbf{Normal}(\mu,\tau^{2})\quad l=1,2,\dots,K$$
$${\sigma}_{l}^{2}|K,a,b\overset{i,i.d}{\sim}\textbf{Inverse-Gamma}(a,b) \quad l=1,2,\dots,K$$
$$y_{i}|z_{i}=l,K,\mu_{l},\sigma_{l}^{2}\overset{i,i.d}{\sim}\textbf{Normal}(\mu_{l},\sigma_{l}^{2})\quad i=1,2,\dots,n$$

$\nu_{1},\nu_{2},\alpha,\mu,\tau^{2},a$ and $b$ are assumed to be fixed hyperparameters. All notations follow conventions followed in Wikipedia.

Can a Gibbs sampler be designed for this model? While attempting to do so, I faced trouble with deriving the full conditional of the number of mixture components K, as well as the full conditional of $\lambda$. I believe that perhaps one or more Metroplis-Hastings steps is(are) required in order to develop the MCMC algorithm I want, often referrred to as a Metroplis-within-Gibbs algorithm. What would be the Metroplis-Hastings step(s) and the proposal distribution(s) in that case?

**Edit:** It seems that it is not possible to build a traditional Gibbs sampler or Metropolois=within-Gibbs sampler and I was referred to Reversible MCMC algorithms proposed by Richardon and Green. What could be an appropriate Reversible MCMC algorithm appropriate for this model?

Comment: A Gibbs sampler cannot be constructed in this variable dimension setting.  Are you aware of Richardson & Green (1997)?

Comment: I went through the reference and they propose a Reversible Jump MCMC algorithm where the state vectors in different MCMC iterations are allowed to be different. If I understood correctly, the additional parameter value to be generated while transitioning from a lower to a higher dimensional state vector is generated from a distribution independently of the other parameter values. This is problematic here because the Dirichlet parameters must sum to 1 and cannot be independently sampled. I will edit my original question in the light of this knowledge.

Comment: The reversible jump algorithm of Richardson & Green (1997) was purposely designed for this setting.

Comment: Concerning the Dirichlet parameters, it is easy to turn a $p$-dimension probability vector into a $p+1$- or $p-1$-dimension probability vector by adding or removing one term and renormalising.